# Blurry image (NSTextAttachment) on NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I'm using NSAttributedString to include images in a string. However, the images are sometimes blurry like if were draw on a non-integer frame.

I tried to make sure the bound of each NSTextAttachment is of integer size, but that doesn't seem to help. Any tips on how to make sure it's not blurry?

See attached screenshot, the first bus is not blurry but the second is.

[image]

Comment: How do you render the attributed string? (`UILabel`, `CATextLayer`, other)

Comment: I'll try with CATextLayer

Comment: It didn't. I didn't find an answer to this question unfortunately. Ended up letting it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a category on NSAttributedString.

Basically, you need to get the NSTextAttachment's frame and add the missing fractional part of its X coordinate to have it round up nicely.

```
- (void)applyBlurrinessFixToAttachments {
    [self enumerateAttribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        if (![value isKindOfClass:[NSTextAttachment class]]) {
            return;
        }
        NSTextAttachment *attachment = (NSTextAttachment*)value;
        CGRect bounds = attachment.bounds;
        CGRect attributedStringRect = [self boundingRectForCharacterRange:range];

        double integral;
        double fractional = modf(attributedStringRect.origin.x, &integral);
        if (fractional > 0) {
            double roundedXOrigin = 1.0 - fractional;

            // If X coordinate starts at 0.7, add 0.3 to it
            bounds.origin.x += roundedXOrigin;
            attachment.bounds = bounds;
        }
    }];
}

- (CGRect)boundingRectForCharacterRange:(NSRange)range {
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:self];
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

    NSRange glyphRange;
    [layoutManager characterRangeForGlyphRange:range actualGlyphRange:&glyphRange];

    return [layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange inTextContainer:textContainer];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with me. `fractional` is always 0. All values are integral.

Comment: If all values are already integral you probably don't have the same exact issue that was posted here. Maybe check to make sure your images don't have half-point values (i.e. 51x51px could be blurry on @2x)

Comment: They don't, but you probably apply `applyBlurrinessFixToAttachments` after it was rendered in a text container. I can't do that since it's in an `NSMenuItem`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code for image round

**UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(14, 14), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);**

```
-(UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image radius: (float) radius {
CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 14, 14);
imageLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;

imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(14, 14), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return roundedImage;
}
```

Comment: for image resizing, one must first determine the target size to scale